# Second conditional or "be to do something" in an if clause?

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

Is there any difference between these sentences?

> 1. "If anything **happened** to her, I would help her."
> 2. "If anything **was to happen** to her, I would help her."
> 3. "If anything **is to happen** to her, I will help her."

To me sound like the third sentence conveys that it is more likely to happen something to the girl than in the second or first sentence. But I can't see the difference between the first and the second sentence, besides the second one being somewhat more formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If anything happens to her, I will help her.* This is presented as a real future possibility. Many student grammars and course books call this a 'first conditional' sentence.

*If anything is to happen to her,  I will help her.* This sentence would be natural only if the speaker knew that something was planned to happen.

*If anything happened to her, I would help her*. This is presented as a hypothetical situation, a less real possibility than in the first sentence. Many student grammars and course books call this a 'second conditional' sentence.

*If anything was/were to happen to her, I would help her*. This is simply a slightly more formal version of the third sentence.

Note that, while *was/were to* is natural, if formal, in second conditional sentences, with no real change of meaning if they are not used, 'am/are/is to' in first conditional sentences always convey some idea of a plan or obligation.

Answer (score 0):

Very brief, & I'm no grammarian, but...

1. General worry about a possible future situation.
2. Same, but a more passive structure. Perhaps implies a specific possible scenario, or a greater emotional distance from the subject - though I'd also say 'better English' in writing, if not conversation.
3. Sense of impending doom. The situation is unfolding right now.